# C Program to Predict entry for Linear Least-Squares Fit

Tags: c

Can anyone help me fix my C code?

I have already made the formula for Linear Least-Squares Fit to fit data entered by the User.

Where I am having issues with having my program read in a series of x values (where number is known advance, but no more than 100 values) until the user enters the sentinel value -100000.  Then prints out a table of values for the least-fit line y=mx+b in two tab-separated. I have not learned to use the getch() function yet so I Cannot use the  header to perform this.

This is what I have come up with so far (I am adding the entire code):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int x[30],X=0,xx=0,xy=0,y[30],Y=0,n,
    bnum,bden,mnum,mden,a[30],N,Yn;

 float b=0.0,m=0.0;
 int i=0,sent=0;
 printf("Enter the number of ordered pairs\n");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 printf("Enter the ordered pairs\n");
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
      scanf("%d%d",&x[i],&y[i]);
      printf("\n");
 }
 printf("The ordered pairs are \n");
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     printf("%2d%2d",x[i],y[i]);
     printf("\n");
 }

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
      X=X+x[i];         //Sum of values in x array
      xx=xx+x[i]*x[i];  //Sum of square of values in x array
      xy=xy+x[i]*y[i];  //Sum of product of values of x and y array
      Y=Y+y[i];         //Sum of values in y array
 }
 bnum=(xx*Y)-(X*xy);
 bden=(n*xx)-(X*X);

 // y intercept
 b=bnum/bden;
 printf("The Y intercept b = %.2f \n",b);
 mnum=(n*xy)-(X*Y);
 mden=bden;

 //slope
 m=mnum/mden;
 printf("The slope m = %.2f \n",m);
 i=0;

// reading set of x values
 while(sent!=-100000)
 {
      printf("Enter the x values\n");
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
      i=i++;
      printf("If done enter -100000 or enter another number to continue\n");
      scanf("%d",&sent);
 }
 N=i;
  printf("x y\n");
 for(i=0;i<N;i++)
 {
      Yn=(m*a[i])+b;
      printf("%3d%3d\n",a[i],Yn);
 }
 return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your title says C, your questions mentions C# and this is tagged as C#, but this looks an awful lot like C to me.

Comment: @CodingGorilla. Its C and I just changed it to that.

Comment: If *"no more than 100 values"* why have you defined `int x[30]` etc? You have not made it clear exactly what your problem is. Surely not `getch()`?

Comment: `b=bnum/bden;` being both bnum and bden two `int`s will end up in an integer division, not what you want. Same for `m`. Are you sure the data need to be `int`?

Comment: BTW if you check the return value of scanf, you could break the loop without a sentinel when scanf fails.